# React - Show the image instead of the string

Tags: hook

The following code output the image path as a string instead of showing the image:

```
    <ul>
      {front.map((card) => (
        <li key={card.id}>
          {card.originalText
            ? card.originalText
            : `<img src=${card.imgURL} alt="sample">`}
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
```

If the card.originalText doesn't exist, it should show an image, but the output is a string like this:

https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/react-apps-e06b2.appspot.com/o/images%2Fimage42.jpg?alt=media&token=1dce5cc7-7ce4-47eb-b823-cdf3232d7a2e alt="sample">

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Maybe you should return jsx element instead template string? :) Just remove quotes and dollar symbol, then it should work as expected.

Comment: {card.originalText
? card.originalText
: <img src={card.imgURL}>
 }  I already tried it, but it causes error.

Comment: What kind of error?

Comment: Parsing error: Expected corresponding JSX closing tag for <img>

Comment: Ah, ok, I've got it. You possibly should use it like <img... />, not like <img... >.

Comment: OMG. It really works. Thanks mate.  <img src={card.imgURL} alt='sample' />